# Can Lord Brahma give moksha? Can jivas enter Satyaloka after death?

Tags: brahma, moksha

It is said that Lord Vishnu and Lord Shiva can give moksha to Their devotees in Their respective abodes i.e. Vaikuntha and Kailasha respectively. Now my question is whether or not, Lord Brahma give moksha? Can jivas after death attain Satyaloka (the abode of Lord Brahma)?

Comment: Keep in mind that Moksha is a concept of being free. One who attains the Moksha get freed from the cycle of life and death. Also in various puranas it's been mentioned that each god has their own adobes like Ganeshloka for lord Ganesha. IN Ganesh purana there are mentions of multiple lokas being watched by a devotee of lord Ganesha while on the way to Ganeshloka.
So yes each god is capable of helping and guiding their devotees to the Moksha and each god has their own Adobes(Which are nothing but the place where the respective god lives).

Comment: Definitely . why such a rudimentary question ?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>For time being  I am only answering your question -  can Jivas after death attain Satyaloka?</sub>

The answer is **Yes**. The Yogi's and ordinary persons (dvija)  both can attain Satya-loka after death.

It's said in [**Brihad Aryanaka Upanishad**](https://archive.org/stream/UpanishadBhashyaGitaPressGorakhpur/Upanishad%20Bhashya%20-%20Gita%20Press%20Gorakhpur#page/n1315/mode/2up)   Chapter 6 -Brahman 2 - Mantra 15 that ,a ordinary Gruhastha who knows the Panchagni Vidya and who worship Brahma or Hiranyagarbha with devotion in forest reach Brahma-Loka.

---

Also the same detail description of Nivrutti Margi dvija ,attening Brahma loka through Devyana path  is given in  Canto 7 -Chapter 15 -Verses 52-55 of  [**Shreemad Bhagvat Purana.**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/15/54)  Below is one verse.

> अग्निः सूर्यो दिवा प्राह्णः शुक्लो राकोत्तरं स्वराट् ।
>  विश्वोऽथ तैजसः
> प्राज्ञस्तुर्य आत्मा समन्वयात् ॥ 7.15.54॥
>
> On his path of ascent, the progressive living entity enters the
> different worlds of fire, the sun, the day, the end of the day, the
> bright fortnight, the full moon, and the passing of the sun in the
> north, along with their presiding demigods. **When he enters Brahmaloka,**
> he enjoys life for many millions of years, and finally his material
> designation comes to an end. He then comes to a subtle designation,
> from which he attains the causal designation, witnessing all previous
> states. Upon the annihilation of this causal state, he attains his
> pure state, in which he identifies with the Supersoul. In this way the
> living entity becomes transcendental.

---

Here  in the another  verse  from same purana this is repeated.

> एतावाञ्जीवलोकस्य संस्थाभेदः समाहृतः ।
>  धर्मस्य ह्यनिमित्तस्य विपाकः
> परमेष्ठ्यसौ [॥ **3.10.9॥**](https://archive.org/stream/BhagavataPuranaMotilalEnglish/Bhagavata%20Purana%20-%20Motilal%20-%20English%20-%20Parts%201%20-%205#page/n277/mode/1up)
>
> Thus is explained the arrangement of world of living beings. The
> region of god Brahma is result of religious duties performed without
> desiring their fruits.

---

So according to Upanishds an ordinary person who knows Panchagni Vidya and worships  (Satya Brahma) with devotion attain Satyaloka. And the puranas in simple manner says this thing as "a person attains Satya or Brahma  loka by performing religious duties without desiring their fruits.

Comment: What's Panchagni Vidya?

Comment: Inn simple words Agnihotra , but we can find more detail about it in Brihad Aryanaka Upanishad Brhana 2 -of Chapter six . I will give you ref. from that upanishad  later in chat  :-)

Comment: BTW you can also check this wiki article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchagni_Vidya

Comment: @SwiftPushkar but how come rituals give jnana as per vedanta ?

Answer (score 2):

The Second Canto (Bhagavatam
2.5.39) also equates Brahmaloka
with the spiritual world,

> mūrdhabhiḥ satya-
>   lokas tu brahma-lokaḥ
>   sanātanaḥ
>
> "Satyaloka, the
>   topmost planetary
>   system, is situated on
>   the head of the form.
>   The spiritual planet
>   Brahmaloka, however,
>   is eternal."

valmiki ramayana say(Rama says to sita):—

> देवगन्धर्वगोलोकान्ब्रह्मलोकां
>   स्तथाऽपरान्।
>   प्राप्नुवन्ति महात्मानो मातापितृपरायणाः।।
>   2.30.37।।
>
> मातापितृपरायणाः people devoted to the
>   service of parents, महात्मानः great
>   men,
>   देवगन्धर्वगोलोकान् the world of the
>   gods, gandharvas, and the cows or
>   Visnu, **ब्रह्मलोकम the world of
>   Brahma**, तथा and, अपरान् other worlds,
>   प्राप्नुवन्ति will attain.
>
> **Great men who are devoted to the
>   service of their parents attain the
>   world of the gods, of gandharvas, of
>   cows, of Visnu, of Brahma and other
>   worlds.**